# How can I add a line or some symbols like (&&&&&) to separate outputs from a text file using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, search, text

I have a big text file which combines 50 survey responses. I already took some initial data cleaning process, and I'd like to extract responses from each question. How can I do that?

The sample text file looks like this:

[image: Text data]

I tried to extract all answers for question 1, but I want to add a line between each response or some symbols to separate those responses. How can I do that?

```
with open("Testing.txt","r") as input:
with open("Q1_output_testing111.txt","w") as output: 
    for line in input:
        if line.strip() == "1. How do you like this product?":
            copy = True
        elif line.strip() == "2. Will you refer this product to your friends?":
            copy = False
        elif not line.strip(): continue
        elif copy:
            output.write(line)
```

The actual results:

[image: Actual results]

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to just change

```
 if line.strip() == "1. How do you like this product?":
     copy = True
```

to something like

```
 if line.strip() == "1. How do you like this product?":
     output.write('&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\n')
     copy = True
```

so every time the first question in each set is encountered, a separator line is printed before the copied lines.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the readlines() function which will return all the data from the file in a list
and list will contain the every thing including the newline character '\n' and you can find the index of the newline charcter and can add any symbol you want to add to the line previous to the newline charcter.